# Callback of .animate() gets called twice jquery

Tags: jquery, callback

Since I added some `scrollTop`-animation, some parts of my callback get called twice:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300,function() {
    $('#content').load(window.location.href, postdata, function() {                 
        $('#step2').addClass('stepactive').hide().fadeIn(700, function() {
            $('#content').show('slide',800);                    
        });
    });
});
```

It only seems to repeat the `.show()`, at least I don't have the impression that the `load()` or the `.fadeIn()` get called a second time too. The `.show()` gets repeated as soon as it has finished for the first time. Setting the scrollTop animation-speed to `0` didn't help by the way!

I assume it has something to do with the animation-queue, but I can't figure out how to find a workaround and especially *why* this is happening.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

[`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) calls its callback once for *each element* in the set you call `animate` on:

> If supplied, the `start`, `step`, `progress`, `complete`, `done`, `fail`, and `always` callbacks are called on a *per-element basis*...

Since you're animating two elements (the `html` element, and the `body` element), you're getting two callbacks. *(For anyone wondering* why *the OP is animating two elements, it's because the animation works on `body` on some browsers but on `html` on other browsers.)*

To get a *single* callback when the animation is complete, the `animate` docs point you at using the [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method to get a promise for the animation queue, then using `then` to queue the callback:

```
$("html, body").animate(/*...*/)
    .promise().then(function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
```

*(Note: Kevin B pointed this out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8791175/157247) when the question was first asked. I didn't until four years later when I noticed it was missing, added it, and...then saw Kevin's answer. Please give his answer the love it deserves. I figured as this is the accepted answer, I should leave it in.)*

Here's an example showing both the individual element callbacks, and the overall completion callback:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#one, #two").animate({
    marginLeft: "30em"
  }, function() {
    // Called per element
    display("Done animating " + this.id);
  }).promise().then(function() {
    // Called when the animation in total is complete
    display("Done with animation");
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="one">I'm one</div>
<div id="two">I'm two</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah that was the reason and actually I can't recall why I ever wrote `html, body`. Time to turn my brain back on. Thanks

Comment: Probably because animating just html won't work in Webkit, and just body won't work in Opera. Using both will ensure it always works, but will trigger the callback twice in Firefox. (I may have gotten the browsers wrong...)

Comment: `html` is required for IE, and the callback will fire twice for most other browsers. I'm trying to work a solution to the same problem.

Comment: I dealt with it by creating a flag:

`var ranOne = false;
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo
}, scrollTime, 'swing', function () {
   if (ranOne) {
  ...action...
  ranOne = false;
   } else {
  ranOne = true;
   }
});`

It feels hacky, but having to use "body,html" is kind of hacky in the first place, so. (ech sorry for lack of line breaks, guess comments don't show them)

Comment: Unbelievable! I spent hours trying to make my scrolling animation work properly with $("html,body") so that it wouldn't fire twice, and this answer is what saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 178):

To get a single callback for the completion of multiple element animations, use deferred objects.

```
$(".myClass").animate({
  marginLeft: "30em"
}).promise().done(function(){
  alert("Done animating");
});
```

When you call `.animate` on a collection, each element in the collection is animated individually. When each one is done, the callback is called. This means if you animate eight elements, you'll get eight callbacks. The `.promise().done(...)` solution instead gives you a single callback when *all animations* on those eight elements are complete. This does have a side-effect in that if there are any *other* animations occurring on any of those eight elements the callback won't occur until those animations are done as well.

See the jQuery API for detailed description of the [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: This is solved problem about what we want to do on finished the animation but issue about twice call and got +1 for that, but i don't know if animate process is called twice or not?!

Comment: The animate process isn't called twice, the callback is called once for each selected element. So, if you select 8 list items and animate them to the left, the callback will be executed 8 times. My solution gives you a single callback for when all 8 are finished.

Comment: @KevinB, good solution, and it helped resolved my own callback issues as well. Thanks.

Comment: I thought this was an intriguing answer, but unfortunately it has unintended consequences. The promise doesn't just delay callback execution until the elements of the jQuery set have finished the current animation (which would be great). It is resolved only after _all pending animations_ of the set are done. So if a second animation is set up while the first is still running, the callback intended for the first animation does not run until after the second animation is over. See [this bin](http://jsbin.com/haboso/2/edit?js,output).

Comment: That is correct, it waits for *all current* animations to complete for the selected elements. It is not smart enough to only wait for the ones started in this chain(nor should it be)

Comment: I just got an upvote on my answer, was curious what it was, saw that it wasn't "getting" the reason for doing `html, body` and didn't mention `promise`, and added that. Then I saw your answer. Going back to edit in a link to yours from mine.