# jquery callback on animation

Tags: jquery, callback

I want to add a callback onto this animate function --

```
$("a#goto-3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#landpoint-3").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic'
    );
    return false; 
});
```

I can do it onto the scrollTop with this...

```
$("a#goto-2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#landpoint-2").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic', function() {
         document.write('complete');  
       });
    return false; 
});
```

..but having no luck getting it onto the animate function - I know this one should be super straightforward.... thanks in advance..

Comment: i assume you looked at the API?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#landpoint-3").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic', function() {
       // animation completed code
   }
);
```

See the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Or you could use [.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) like this:

```
$.when($('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#landpoint-3").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic'))
.then(function() {
    // both animations completed code!
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's the 2 element problem (`html` and `body`). What you can do is use `.when()` and `.then()` to add a callback when *both* animations are finished. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a#goto-3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#landpoint-3").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic', function() { callback stuff here; }
    );
    return false; 
});
```

Make sure you only animate ONE element, you are animating on both html and body.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/HQUaD/2/

Comment: Hi this is still callback is still on the scrollTop, and not the animate itself - if I put a document.write in there as in ...

    $("a#goto-3").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#landpoint-3").offset().top}, 1000, 'easeInOutCubic', function() { callback stuff here; }
        );
        return false; 
    });

the result writes 'completecomplete' ... ?

Comment: Its because you are animating two elements (html and body)

Comment: ahah - this error is a result of animating two elements at once - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790752/callback-of-animate-gets-called-twice-jquery