# jQuery - .click() not working in .animate callback

Tags: jquery

When the user clicks a link, I need to scroll up to the `showemaildiv` and then fire a click event to open the email data. This works:

```
$(".showemaillink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailid = $(this).attr('data-emailid');
        var emaildiv = $(".showemaildiv[data-id='" + emailid + "']");

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: emaildiv.offset().top
        }, 500);

        emaildiv.click();
    });
```

But to make it a little nicer, I'd like the email to expand after the animate so I'm using a callback. In this case, however, `emaildiv.click()` is not working although the `alert` is - what is wrong here?

```
 $(".showemaillink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailid = $(this).attr('data-emailid');
        var emaildiv = $(".showemaildiv[data-id='" + emailid + "']");

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: emaildiv.offset().top
        }, 500, function(){
                emaildiv.click();
                alert('callback fired');
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok and working (I've tried it).
But there may be a problem with the callback function - it is called twice, for every element you are animating - first time for html and second time for body.

You can read more about it here: [Callback of .animate() gets called twice jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790752/callback-of-animate-gets-called-twice-jquery)

If you have in your `emaildiv` click event some actions that negate previous actions (like toggle) it looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes - you are correct and I should have realised that the two callbacks were clicking my `emaildiv` twice - one to open and one to shut again!! The code in your link fixed the issue :)