# jQuery animate function doesn't work on Firefox 11 & 12

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am not sure if this is specific to Firefox 11 & 12 but jQuery's animate function is not working anymore.

I created a fiddle to demonstrate this - http://jsfiddle.net/hndy4/

The problem exists both on Firefox 12 (Ubuntu) and Firefox 11 (MAC). Any ideas or workarounds?

P.S. - The demo works fine on Chrome, Safari

Comment: possible duplicate of [animate scrollTop not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 4545 }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Did you mean something like this