# Jquery/Javascript not working on Firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

I just found out that my script is working fine in Chrome, but not in FireFox - and I can't figure out why.

This is the site in development: [www.fireflycovers.com](http://www.fireflycovers.com)

The script should execute when one of the **round green buttons** is clicked. (scrolls the window to the next container)

The script looks like this at the moment:

```
$('.scroll').css('display' , 'block');
$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    var container = $(this).parent();

    // Scans if last container in group
    while (document != container[0] && 
           container.find('~.col, ~:has(.col)').length == 0) {

           // If so, search siblings of parent instead
           var container = container.parent(),
               nextdiv = container.nextAll('.col, :has(.col)').first();
    }

    // Back to first .col (when no next .col)
    if (nextdiv.length == 0) {
        nextdiv = $(document).find('.col:first')
    };

    // Animates scrolling to new position
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:nextdiv.offset().top}, 1000);  
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try debugging at all? As in, putting `console.log` statements throughout your method to see what the values of things are at certain times and watching it execute? Anyway, does using this help at all?

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:nextdiv.offset().top}, 1000);
```

Verified from [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

You need `html` because firefox behaves differently when it comes to `overflow`.

Comment: Brilliant! You're a Hero!! :-D

Comment: @Arrowcatch Haha no problem, glad it fixed it for you!