# jquery scrollTop not working

Tags: jquery, html, syntax, slide

So I'm trying to make it that then when you click a link in a carousel it scrolls you down the page to the content.

Here is my jquery:

```
$('#picks li a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

However I recieve this error in my console 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://hutchcreative.co.uk/rod/other/#galleryDetails

That is the correct link location but not sure how to correct it so that jquery adds in the slide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the attribute href is referencing the id of an element, you need to use the `#` before the actuall ID

```
$('#picks li a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( '#'+$.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Also note, that this will be triggered twice; I know you added html in order to work with firefox, as [I Did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox) a while a go,

So you could:

```
$('#picks li a').click(function(){
        $(Query.browser.mozilla ? "html" : "body").animate({
            scrollTop: $( '#'+$.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

or, at least stop the animation before:

```
$('#picks li a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').stop(true,true).animate({
            scrollTop: $( '#'+$.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

To prevent some issues with this double call

Answer (score 0):

The `attr` method is returning a string with the entire URL. You need to get rid of everything before the "#" in the string. You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the index of the "#" character, and you can use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get only the portion of the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I go to your link, the first problem i get is that `$` is undefined, when i try to test from console. However `jQuery` works fine, so your lib is obviously loaded.

The next prob is you code. You're calling for `href` which is getting the whole link and not just the hash mark.

```
jQuery('#picks li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    id = '#' + id[id.length-1];
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( id ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways, none worked.

For me this works with Angularjs combined.

```
$( "html, body" ).scrollTop( $("#main_div").offset().top );
```

main_div is the id in any HTML element you want.

I don't like Angularjs hashtags at the top of the URL, that's why I didn't use them.

```
$location.hash('main_div');
```

I think the animate thing complicates this.