# Go to top smooth scroll button doesn't work in Firefox on OSX

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, smooth-scrolling

I've been working on this site:
http://buchstudio.com/projects/spis.html

The red hand icon on right works fine in every browser except Firefox and I can't figure out why?

Here the code:

```
<body id="gototop">
<nav>
<p><a href="../about.html" class="nav_about p_about">About</a></p>
<a href="../buchstudio.html" class="nav_logo"><h5>B</h5></a>
<a href="#gototop"><img class="nav_gototop" src="../img/gototop.png" alt="Go to top"></a>
</nav>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Denne funktion fanger #");
        console.log(event);

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

(I'm testing in OSX)

Comment: Refer to this earlier post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Try this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/