# Is there any way to position the scroll bar using css?

Tags: html, css

I am using `jquerymobile 1.4.2`.
I tried with all the functions which are specified using `jquery(scrollTop)`.But it snot working in my page.
Is it possible to `scroll` to a `specific position` using **css** when we **reload** a page or when `submit a button`.

Comment: I tried wit this 
 $(document).ready(function() {
   
   
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:30}, 'slow');
   
            });  But its not working so i thought to use css

Comment: This is a http://jsbin.com/dasiguje/5/edit some times it works some time it won't,when you change the value i think you will come to in firefox

Comment: Check this one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have the script at the top of the page. I see you wrapped it in a `$(document).ready()` but that alone isn't always guaranteed to work, like in your case. `$(document).ready` fires when the dom is loaded, the dom tells the browser that somewhere in the page there is an image, but the browser won't know the size (in pixels) of that image until it's completely loaded. This causes your issue:
1) dom starts loading
2) dom is done, `$(document).ready()` fires
3) the script tries to animate the `scrollTop` but it won't work because the page has not yet reached its complete height (because the images are not loaded), so there is no scrollbar.
4) the images load but the script has already done its job

Solutions:
1) add `height` and `width` attributes to your images
2) use `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

A hint for the future: if the problem is "sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't" it's a timing problem 90% (or even more) of the times. So  try to figure out what happens and when.

Comment: Thanq very much its workingfine. I was working on it since from yesterday afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that in CSS. Sorry!

Maybe, you should try for this one : [`jQuery.mobile.silentScroll()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/)