# jQuery .data() Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Any reason or knowledge to why using jQuery's .data() won't do anything on Firefox? I have built the following and it works great on Chrome/Safari but on Firefox it doesn't.

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-header-container .top-section.outer').data('size','big');
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $headerTop = $('.top-header-container .top-section.outer');
    if ( $('body').scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        if ($headerTop.data('size') == 'big') {
            $headerTop.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height: '40px'
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.find('.main-menu-container').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.find('.site-logo-big').fadeOut(300, function() {
                $headerTop.find('.site-logo-small').fadeIn(300);
            });
            $headerTop.find('.social-container-big').fadeOut(300, function() {
                $headerTop.find('.social-container-small').fadeIn(300);
            });
            $('.content-container').stop().animate({
                marginTop: '130px'
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.addClass('small');
        }
    } else {
        if ($headerTop.data('size') == 'small') {
            $headerTop.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height: '205px'
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.find('.main-menu-container').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.find('.site-logo-small').fadeOut(300, function() {
                $headerTop.find('.site-logo-big').fadeIn(300);
            });
            $headerTop.find('.social-container-small').fadeOut(300, function() {
                $headerTop.find('.social-container-big').fadeIn(300);
            });
            $('.content-container').stop().animate({
                marginTop: '285px'
            }, 600);
            $headerTop.removeClass('small');
        }  
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** Adding `console.log('test');` directly below `$(window).scroll(function() {` so before any .data() is used, it shows in the FF console. BUT if I put a console.log below `if ( $('body').scrollTop() > 0 ) {` nothing happens in Firefox, but does in Chrome. Does `scrollTop` work in FF?

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the JS console?

Comment: @ComFreek No, that's the weird thing. It carries out all the rest of the JS in that file fine... before and after this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing this question: [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

The issue was that FF uses `html` as the overflow, whereas other browsers else uses `body`. However, adding body `body,html` results in it working in FF, but not in Chrome. The best solution for this is to use `$(window).scrollTop()` rather than `$('body').scrollTop()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The .data() method works just fine on Firefox and so does .scrollTop().

The simple solution to your problem is:
Instead of using `if ( $('body').scrollTop() > 0 )` use `if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 )`

A little theory:

If you remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your document, `$('body').scrollTop()` will work just fine.
I cannot properly explain why this happens. It has got something to do with element layout attributes in HTML5. But I would not recommend removing the HTML5 declaration since it is the standard.