# Navbar Specific jQuery Scroll Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, header, scroll

I have a fixed header, of which has a handful of links. Now, this code is almost where I need it to be to work, the main issue being that there's a delay when executing the second function. It does it's intended purpose of scrolling to the top of the page when the bound element is clicked, but it does so slowly at first, before continuing at the specified speed. I'm sure there's also a way to DRY this up and turn it into a single function instead of two separate ones. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  $("[href^='#']").on("click", function( e ) {  
    $("body, html").animate({ 
      scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top-$('.header').height()-$('.header').outerHeight()
    }, 800); 
    e.preventDefault();
  });    
});


$(function(){
    $("#home").on("click", function( e ){
        $("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9by4n5cu/1/

Comment: could you do a fiddle?

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive..

http://jsfiddle.net/9by4n5cu/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge two function like bellow,

```
  $(function() {
    $("[href^='#']").on("click", function( e ) {  

      var target = $(this).attr('href');

      var scrollTop = $( target ).offset().top-$('.header').height()-$('.header').outerHeight();

      if ( target =='#home'){
         scrollTop = 0;
      }

      $("body, html").animate({
              scrollTop: scrollTop
          }, 800);

      e.preventDefault();


    });

  });
```

Demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahim12/9by4n5cu/3/

Comment: Well done! Thank you Ibrahim, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

it's delayed because you trigger the `animate` twice, so like what you say, you need to merge the `function` as one like this

```
$(function () {
    $("[href^='#']").on("click", function (e)  {
        var link = $(this);
        var $header = $('.header')
        var top = link.attr("id") == "home" ? 0 : $(link.attr('href')).offset().top - $header.height() - $header.outerHeight()

        //$("html").animate({

        $("body, html").animate({    // Use $("body, html") to work on all browser as noted by Ibrahim
            scrollTop: top
        }, 800);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I use the first click function, then check whether the id of the `link` that's clicked is `home`, if yes, set the `top` to 0, else do the calculation as you do before.

here's the updated <strike>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/9by4n5cu/2/)</strike> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/9by4n5cu/6/)

Comment: I really want this to work, because it's so effing dry and beautiful, but even the jfiddle is unresponsive. Something's off mate.

Comment: @PMills, what didn't work and unresponsive? It's working fine in my browser.

Comment: `$("html").animate({` -> change this line to `$("body, html").animate({` to work on all browsers.

Comment: @Ibrahim, thanks for the info :), I just know now that the `overflow` places is different for each browser from [this answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8149216) after what you said, thanks a lot :)