# JavaScript works in Chrome not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a navbar that works in Chrome(41.0.2272.89) but not in Firefox(36.0.1).

HTML

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li  class="active"><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(home)" title="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(about)" title="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(clients)" title="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(portfolio)" title="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(contact)" title="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Using a simple onclick, it will activate my JS

JS

```
function scrollTo(element) {
if(element == document.getElementById('home')) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 54
    }, 500);
} else {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 53 
    }, 500);
}}
```

It seem the JS activates in Chrome but not in Firefox.

What is supposed to happen is that when you click a item, the site will scroll down to it. This used to work fine, but now it suddenly now longer works.

Example [HERE](http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/mtletcher/)

Comment: Instead of `html, body` try `$(document)`

Comment: This question looks similar. Maybe these answers have your solution . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery why use the inline onclick handlers. You could just call the .click or .on('click' , .....) jQuery method.

Comment: @mikeLspohn, afraid it doesn't help. I'm already using 'html, body' as mentioned in that answer.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, tried it and didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollTo must be a reserved word due to their own [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) function.

```
function moveTo(element) {
if(element == document.getElementById("home")) {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 54
    }, 500);
} else {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 53 
    }, 500);
}}
```

So changing the function name returned normal functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your onclick definitions are faulty.

Instead of:

```
<li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo(about)" title="#about">About</a></li>
```

Try using single quotes around the DIV names like:

```
<li><a class="navBtn" onclick="scrollTo('about')" title="#about">About</a></li>
```

This will also require some adjustments to the function code as well to handle passing the name of the DIV instead of the object.

Comment: they do function, as they work in Chrome. It's just Firefox not wanting to play ball.