# onclick scroll down calc (100% - 60px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop, scrollto

I'm working on my Tumblr blog and have the following CSS set:

```
img
{
    max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

so the margins (top and bottom) are both 30px.

I'm trying to add two buttons *prev* and *next* that will, when clicked, scroll the page up or down (100% - 60px).

This is the JS I have:

```
$(function() {
    $("#next").on("click", function() {
        $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY+100}, 100);
        return false;
    });
}); 

$(function() {
    $("#previous").on("click", function() {
        $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY-100}, 100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cztqjwb2/1/

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks.

PS: also I don't know why it work only on Safari.

Comment: Please post the code and any relevant information in your question, don't outsource it. If the link dies, your question dies with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY + 100}, 100);
```

This scrolls to *current position + 100px*. Assuming by `100% - 60px` you mean *window height - 60px* (as opposed to *document height*), replace that `100` with `(window.innerHeight - 60)`.

```
$("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY + window.innerHeight}, 100);
```

I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cztqjwb2/2/) accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works only in Safari though? @Siguza

Comment: It actually works with Safari, Chrome and Opera, just not in Firefox (IE I didn't test and I don't care). See [this SO question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox) for why that is and how to work around it. Updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cztqjwb2/4/) again.