# section snap to window (firefox issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox, scroll

I have written a simple custom section snapping script, works great in chrome and safari, but after nothing happens in firefox...

What it is does:

When scrolling stops it checks the direction and location of each secrion... if the top of a section is within a certain range either go to the top of the page or bottom. (scroll directions is also checked). Also, it accounts for the height of a fixed header. Like I said works in Chrome and Safari. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var animating = false;
    var mainHeader = $('#main-header');

    var items = $("section");
    var lastOffset = 0;
    var scrollDir = 'none';


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowHeight = $(this).height();
        var currOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
        var headerHeight = mainHeader.outerHeight();

        if (currOffset > lastOffset) {
            scrollDir = 'down';
        } else {
            scrollDir = 'up';
        }
        lastOffset = currOffset;



        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        if (!animating) {
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                items.each(function(key, value) {
                        var currentItem = $(value);
                        var sectionOffset = currentItem.offset().top;
                        var sectionDist = sectionOffset - currOffset;
                    if ( scrollDir === 'up' && sectionDist > windowHeight*0.15 && sectionDist < windowHeight ) {
                        animating = true;
                        $('body').animate( { scrollTop: sectionOffset-windowHeight + 'px' }, 250);
                        setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 300);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if ( scrollDir === 'down' && sectionDist < windowHeight*0.85 && sectionDist > 0 ) {
                        animating = true;
                        $('body').animate( { scrollTop: sectionOffset-headerHeight + 'px' }, 250);
                        setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 300);
                        return false;
                    }
              });
            }, 200));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to let you know. This feature is available in [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) when using the option `fitToSection` and `autoScrolling:false` as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html).

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro but I did actually want the auto scrolling to happen at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here...
[Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

Firefox places the overflow at the html level, unless specifically styled to behave differently.

To get it to work in Firefox, use

```
$('body,html').animate( ... );
```