# Why onclick event doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a javascript code that works in Chrome but it refuses to work in Mozilla Firefox. Why is that so?

My [Codepen sandbox](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEGJVd).

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll-arrows">CLICK TO SCROLL</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  height: 2000vh;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.scroll-arrows', function() {
  return $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: 400
  }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: The problem is not with handling the "click" event; that works fine, as a quick introduction of a `console.log()` call would show you.

Comment: To handle FF, use `$('html, body').animate({...});`. FYI, your `return` statement has no meaning here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

You have to use `$('body,html').animate( {scrollTop: 400}, 'slow');`