# Scroll Top doesn't Working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I know, this question have been asked for hundred times but none of the solutions did help me actually.

Scroll Top does not work on firefox but it does in chrome and safari.

here my js

```
function scroll_top (){
  $("body").append("<div id='scroll-top'><i class='fa fa-angle-up'></i></div>")
  $('#scroll-top').on( 'click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});
      return false;
  });
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > 700 ) {
    $('#scroll-top').fadeIn();

  } else {

    $('#scroll-top').fadeOut();
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 700 ) {
      $('#scroll-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#scroll-top').fadeOut();
    } 
  })

}
```

and my html

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Which `scrollTop` doesn't work? `animate({scrollTop: 0})` or `$(window).scrollTop()`?

Comment: None of them works actually also there is no error in js console

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: hi you can actually check from here www.metropolyos.com @Barmar

Comment: the `scrollTop` prop goes on body or documentElement (in quirks)

Answer (score 0):

The command `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});` does not work on your website in Firefox. There are some problems in Firefox, which were already discussed intensively on stackoverflow.

To fix your problem in Firefox, you need to set some CSS properties to `<html>` and `<body>` according to the following answer. Then, it works. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149216

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`document.getElementById("scroll-top").scrollTop = 0;`