# Go to top button not working in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, scrolltop

I have a 'gototop' button. When the user clicks on the button the page will scroll up. It works fine in Safari and Chrome, but not working on Firefox. I think have enabled JavaScript in Firefox. Not sure why it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(window).scroll (function(){
     if($(this).scrollTop()>90) {
       $('.goToTop').fadeIn(); }
     else{
       $('.goToTop').fadeOut(); 
    }
  });

  var goToTop = document.getElementsByClassName("goToTop")[0];

  goToTop.onclick = function(){  
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0},600); 
  };
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/45x45?text=^" class='goToTop' style="background: #fff url({{ 'back-to-top.png' | asset_url }}) no-repeat ;  
  bottom:1px;display:block;opacity:.8; border-radius: 20px;position:fixed;right:1em;height:45px;width:45px; z-index:999"> 
  <div class="sixteen columns page">
     {{ page.content }}   
 </div>
```

Comment: Try `$('body, html').animate({...})`

Comment: It works wonder. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: sorry didn't know there are similar questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate both `body` and `html`.

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},600);
```