# jQuery animate scrollTop issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've build a website for my resume with jQuery for some scroll-based events and animations. The problem is the "Go to top" arrow works fine on Chrome (PC) and Mobile Safari but doesn't seem to work on Firefox.

```
//arrow up show/hide function
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    "use strict";
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 500){
        $(".arrow-up").addClass("arrow-up-clicked");
    } else {
        $(".arrow-up").removeClass("arrow-up-clicked");
    }
});

//arrow up on click event
$(".arrow-up").on("click", function() {
    "use strict";
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "300", "swing");
});
```

Comment: Try to use instead `$(window).animate({...});`  and btw, use `window` instead of `document`

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: update your title from "jQuery doesn't work on Firefox" to "scrollTop is not working on Firefox."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this..

```
$('.arrow-up').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. That definitely helped!