# data-scroll="top" is not scrolling to top in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an anchor tag as shown below

```
<a data-scroll="top" class="show-overlay" href="#edit-event-announcement-1" ref="#edit-event-announcement-1"> Edit Announcement</a>
```

In Chrome, it works and scrolls to the top, but in Firefox it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Please.... provide your code in your question, it doesn't belong here in the comments....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is answered here: [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

> "Firefox places the overflow at the html level, unless specifically
>   styled to behave differently.
>   To get it to work in Firefox, use  `$('body,html').animate( ... );` ..."

hope this helps, cheers!