# scrollTop with jQuery offset not working properly in Firefox unless mouseout occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, offset, scrolltop

The `scrollHash()` function below is intended to scroll to a target anchor while adjusting the position to reflect both the fixed menu and desired `margin-top`.

The function works properly in Chrome, however it only works in Firefox if a `mouseout` event occurs before the function is completed (accounting for the function's `duration` and `setTimeout()`). Otherwise, if the mouse continues hovering over the link in Firefox throughout the function’s execution, the function fails to complete the second step of adjusting the position (subtracting the fixed menu’s height from `offset().top`).

It is worth noting that the problem doesn’t present in JSFiddle + Firefox (using the identical code and version of jQuery, 1.9.1), and I'm running Firefox version 69.0.3 (64-bit).  *Fiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/chayanyc/otkLa90x/*

**Code Snippets**

*CSS:*

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}    
.header_container {height: var(--targetPosition); width: 100vw; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: fixed; top: 0; display: block;}
.main {margin-top: var(--topWrapper); width: 100%;}
.Section {padding: var(--sectPadding) 0; width: 100%;}    

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --sectPadding: 5rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --sectPadding: 9.5rem;
    --targetPosition: 9.3rem;
  }
}
```

*JavaScript:*

```
// SCROLL HASH FUNCTIONS //
window.onhashchange = scrollHash;
function scrollHash() {
    menuHeight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;        
    $('.TargetMark').removeClass('TargetMark')
    if (window.location.hash) {            
      $(window.location.hash).addClass('TargetMark')      
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.TargetMark').offset().top - menuHeight
        }, 100);
    }
}

// SET MARGIN TOP //
var headerHeight;
function setTarget() {
  headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
  headerHeight = headerHeight + "px";
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--topWrapper', headerHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTarget();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    setTarget();
});
```

**console.log output**

```
// SAME OUTPUT IN CHROME VS. FIREFOX 
var offset = $('.TargetMark').offset();
console.log( (offset.top - topHeight) );

// DIFFERING OUTPUT IN CHROME VS. FIREFOX
var $window = $(window);
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $topOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log($topOffset);
});
```

Comment: Try to change `document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight` to `$('#header').height()`

Comment: @sugars - The result remains the same.

Comment: I'm working well on Firefox and chrome.

Comment: Are you referring to it running in both in the JSFiddle, or in its own document?

Comment: Yes, I copy it to an HTML file and run it myself

Comment: @sugars - Do you mind confirming if my document is working for you as well? (To help hone in on where the glitch is.)  http://www.cooperconsulting.net/scrollHash_Function.html

Comment: On Firefox, after clicking the link in the header, the page will scroll to the corresponding anchor point, but when clicking another link, it cannot scroll immediately. You need to click twice or mouseleave and then moveenter, right?

Comment: @sugars - It's meant to always work with just one click, and shouldn't require a `mouseout` event. It performs properly for me in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Are you experiencing a different result?

Comment: Unfortunately, Firefox on my Mac OS is the same as chrome.

Comment: @sugars - Can you clarify what you mean by that? Are both documents (mine and yours) working correctly for you in Firefox? And if so, is your version of Firefox the reason why?